# Count all characters including whitespace and footnotes

Tags: characters

How can I count the characters of my document? I tried characterCount, but it doesn't work. I want to start at a custom point in my document and all characters including whitespace and footnotes should be counted, but not the page numbering.

Comment: I mean the whitespaces between words. The formalities don't specify if line breaks should also count. I think I want to count the characters like Word would do, because that's how others count  their text characters.